# Count cell(s) if another cell shows certain data

Tags: excel

I am struggling work out the formula/function that I should be using for an excel spread sheet I have created.

A questionnaire is being sent out to clients asking for feedback of their recent business. I have one work sheet which will allow me to input the answers for each client and another showing the results.

I would like the results to be shown as a whole group and (using a drop down menu) for each sales adviser.

I have created the drop down menu and I am using the function 'Counta' to obviously count the number of 'yes's or no's etc. for each question.

The problem I have though is when trying to show the results for individual sales advisers I can't figure out which formula/function I should be using.

I have come up with the following:

```
{=IF(H1=Data!B3:B500,COUNTA(Data!$D$3:$D$500),"0")}

 Where:
 H1 = the drop down menu with the list of sales advisers. 
 Data!B3:B500 = the 'Adviser_names'.
 Data!D3:D500 = the results for that inidivdual question.
```

The problem is I can't get the two columns to match each other in the results - i.e. if Data!B3 is the same as H1 then count Data!D3 ONLY; or/and (plus) if Data!B30 is the same as H1 then count Data!D30 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply:

```
=COUNTIFs(Data!B3:B500,H1,Data!$D$3:$D$500,"<>")
```

Comment: I have similar question but this time using the averageifs function: I have expanded the formula a little but just focus on the averageifs part: =IF($H$1="All advisers",AVERAGE(Data!R$3:X$500),AVERAGEIFS(Data!$R$3:$X$500,Data!$B$3:$B$500,$H$1)) The result is #VALUE - I basically want to find the average number but as per my original question - I only want to find the average for specific sales advisers.

Comment: your ranges `Data!$R$3:$X$500` and `Data!$B$3:$B$500` should have same dimmensions. I suggets you to post new question and somebody can help you:)

Comment: you can try this one: `=IF($H$1="All advisers",AVERAGE(Data!R$3:X$500),SUMPRODUCT((Data!$B$3:$B$500=$‌​H$1)*(Data!$R$3:$X$500))/SUMPRODUCT((Data!$B$3:$B$500=$‌​H$1)*(Data!$R$3:$X$500<>""))`

Comment: Thank you - I was mid writing a new question and checked back here to see if anyone had added anything..which you did! However that didn't work. If you would prefer I could write it in a new question?

Comment: ok, post it as new question, I'll look at it:) and also can you eleborate how it didn't work? I've just make a little test and it works fine for me..

Comment: it worked, thank you! for some strange reason my copy and paste was adding in spaces between certain formula - e.g. my eyes would see: $H$1 but when I scrolled through the formula with the arrow keys... there was a space or 2 in between $ and H (and a couple of other locations). Where a sales adviser hasn't got any results would you use the ISERROR function? (to avoid '#DIV/0!' appearing - (it would double the length of the formula but would make it look 'pretty')

Comment: 1) you can use `IFERROR` instear `ISERROR`: `=IFERROR(IF(...),0)`  2) you can also try: `=AVERAGE(IF($H$1="All advisers",Data!$R$‌​3:$X$500,IF(Data!$B$3:$B$500=$‌​H$1,Data!$R$‌​3:$X$500)))` with array entry, i.e. CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: great! I used Iferror - the second one didn't work as it found a "true" average - I guess it was my fault for laying out the data table in a messy way. I.e. R3 = 1 S3= 2 T3=3 etc. - if the answer was "1" and there was only 1 result then I would want the mean to equal 1 of course.. however your array entry didn't "work" because I hadn't put anything in S3, T3 etc. etc. so it thought there were 7 results with 6 of them "0" and one "1" = 1/7 = 0.14! - It doesn't matter anyway as the IFerror worked perfectly